# unit-tests in wakanda with npm scripts

Tags: unit-testing, wakanda

I’m trying to integrate wakanda unit tests into our development workflow, but don’t really know where to start.

My favour would be if I could run unit tests somehow like “npm run test” (as i do for my frontend code) and start the unit tests with my npm script … this way, the tests could easily be executed.

Unfortunately, I have two problems with this:

1. Can’t get wakanda to execute my file wakanda-unit-tests.js with relative file paths
2. If a test fails, wakanda does not throw any exit code that my build would not fail -> how can I generate an exit code for example as described in this article http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Wakanda/0.v5/run.301-1019704.en.html -> `run()` returns the total number of failures, suitable **for use as a process exit status code**.

Any suggestions are very much appreciated :-)

Comment: Sorry Stefan, we are working to provide a better unit test feature for a v2 minor release.

Comment: Hi Yann, thank you for the feedback. For the moment I'm using mocha, chai & chai-http to test the wakanda unit test service through npm scripts as a workaround.

Comment: Our solution will also work with mocha & chai. So there is a good hope that your migration could be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Wakanda `v2.1` provides a way to test your solution SSJS code.
You can write mocha/chai tests in the `/backend/tests` folder.

Here is the official documentation : https://wakanda.github.io/doc/#/guide?section=main-test